# ConfigurationManager not found

Tags: .net, app-config, configurationmanager

I am new to VS 3.5 and I am writing a console app that needs to pull some key values from the app.config file.

I have:

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

and I am trying to reference `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` but this generates an error:

> Name ConfigurationManager is not declared

What am I missing?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to the assembly `System.Configuration.dll`

Comment: Yes, thank you for responding. I did eventually figure that on my own!

Answer (score 27):

> Project -> Add References -> .NET -> select System.Configuration

[image: Project -> Add References -> .NET -> select System.Configuration]

Answer (score 15):

I had to Install NuGet package [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) in my Visual Studio 2019 C# project.

E.g.,

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.7.0
```

Comment: This is the correct way to go for newer Visual Studio installations.

Comment: I've just opened a .NET Framework 4.7.2 console app project in Visual Studio 2022 and it seems to recognise ConfigurationManager with just a reference to System.Configuration. 
 The project has no NuGet packages at all.  It compiles without error or warnings.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem myself and actually included the reference to System.Configuration, and it STILL wouldn't show up.

I had to go to the Build menu, select Clean, and then rebuild.

Posting because in six months when I see this again I'll probably forget what I did...

Comment: I done this , but not worked . So, closed project and then reopen project. worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using System.Configuration;
  OR
Try to add reference by selecting
Project -> Add References -> .NET -> select System.Configuration

now you can use "ConfigurationManager"

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to System.Configuration:

Menu Bar -> Project -> Add Reference... -> .NET (Tab) -> System.Configuration -> OK